# html child element to extend over parent boundaries

Tags: html, css

Basically, as the title states, I want a child element to extend over the parent boundaries. This element is only visible when hovering its parent element.

I'm not allowed to share the whole css, so I tried to create a basic jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XeniaSiskaki/rqekasfm/)

Our layout looks something like:

```
   Fixed top bar
_____________________
S  |  Scrollable body
i  |
d  |
e  |
b  |
a  |
r  |
```

where sidebar is also fixed. Sidebar contains multiple scrollable items.

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
}

.body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.help {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    padding-right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

span:hover + .help-text {
    transition: all 0.2s 0.4s;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.help-text {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1500;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-item">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="help">
        <span>hover over me</span>
        <pre class="help-text">
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
        </pre>
      </div>
      gvregrfvrtyewrfgvrtbh
      vgrewtghwrt
      frgerghrthbed
      hewrtgrhbrwwh
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to avoid having the vertical and horizontal scrollbars and when the help text is shown it should go over the parent div's limits. `z-index` isn't working. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Was able to get rid of the scrollbars when help-text is not shown by changing `visibility` to `display`, but still the text is shown inside parent container when hovered over

Comment: No, not as long as you are using overflow:auto on the container element. But if you say you don’t want scrollbars, then why are you using that in the first place …?

Comment: In our layout we have a top bar, a fixed left sidebar and a body. The sidebar scrolbars (if you ignore the help text) are because the sidebar content is usually larger than screen width and we don't want to have whole page scrollbars because of the sidebar's content length. I hope it's clear what I mean

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: I don't get the downvotes

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use position fixed, be careful this will put the help tool tip in relation to the window, you can use margins to set the position(because by default the fixed position item, appears next to its parent), if you use top and left, it will put the element the in relation to the view port..

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
}

.body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.help {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    padding-right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.help:hover .help-text {
    transition: all 0.2s 0.4s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.help-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-item">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="help">
        <span>hover over me</span>
        <pre class="help-text">
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
        </pre>
      </div>
      gvregrfvrtyewrfgvrtbh
      vgrewtghwrt
      frgerghrthbed
      hewrtgrhbrwwh
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We reuse this help text component and was looking for a more general solution since the component's position is most of the times not specific

Answer (score 0):

try this:

I removed the width of the text-help and and hover in it to continue visible on reading.

```css
.sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sidebar-item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
}

.body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.help {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: default;
    padding-right: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}

span:hover + .help-text {
    transition: all 0.2s 0.4s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.help-text:hover {
    transition: all 0.2s 0.4s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.help-text {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-item">
    <div class="body">
      <div class="help">
        <span>hover over me</span>
        <pre class="help-text">
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
          some test data
        </pre>
      </div>
      gvregrfvrtyewrfgvrtbh
      vgrewtghwrt
      frgerghrthbed
      hewrtgrhbrwwh
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this can work. Most of the times there just isn't enough space to show the help text just inside the parent div in our layout